# Ajax XML request not working properly

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, google-chrome

I am trying to do a simple ajax request to load in some XML when a value in a dropdown is selected. The XML contains image paths that I switch based on what the user selects. It works great in Firefox (I don't get any Javascript errors), but for some reason nothing happens in Chrome. This is what i have so far:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLDoc(url) {

            var xmlhttp;
            var txt, txtBase, txtOverlay1, txtOverlay2, txtBlack, name, img;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
              // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, & Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
            }
            else { 
              // code for IE6 & IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { 

                    txtBase='<img id="original"';
                    txtOverlay1='<img id="overlay1" class="overlay"';
                    txtOverlay2='<img id="overlay2" class="overlay"';
                    txtBlack='<img id="opacity" class="overlay"';

                    img=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
                    name=img[0].getElementsByTagName("NAME");

                    txtBase = txtBase + name[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '/>';
                    txtOverlay1 = txtOverlay1 + name[1].firstChild.nodeValue + '/>';
                    txtOverlay2 = txtOverlay2 + name[2].firstChild.nodeValue + '/>';
                    txtBlack = txtBlack + name[3].firstChild.nodeValue + '/>';

                    txt = txtBase + txtOverlay1 + txtOverlay2 + txtBlack;
                    document.getElementById('inner_container').innerHTML = txt;
                    $(".red").css({"font-size":"2.0em"});
                    $(".blue, .green").css({"font-size":"1.0em"});
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

And i call it using this.

```
            <select>
                <option id="selected">Select a car</option>
                <option onclick="loadXMLDoc('http://www.brandybrowauto.com/files/nissan.xml')">Nissan</option>
                <option onclick="loadXMLDoc('http://www.brandybrowauto.com/files/mazdaspeed3.xml')">Mazdaspeed3</option>
            </select>
```

Any help to get this to work in Chrome would be greatly appreciated, also any hints at making the code better. I'm a beginner at ajax.

Comment: You might find it easier to use jQuery, it will handle AJAX cross-browser compatibility for you.

Comment: Given that you already seem to be using jQuery to set CSS you should defintely use it for Ajax too. You might want to use it to create your new elements also. (As for the actual problem in Chrome - I don't know.)

Comment: I have been meaning to try and switch everything over to all jquery, but i unfortunately and just getting into ajax and would have to do alot of research. But in the meantime there has to be something stupid that im doing/not doing thats causing it to not even load the xml files in chrome. I tried the overrideMime trick, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the status-code. It may happen that the xml-file has been requested before and the server sends another status-code, e.g. 304

jQuery automatic appends a random-parameter to the url to prevent from this(you may do this too).

---

**Edit:**

It seems that the click-handler didn't fire.
Use this markup for the select instead:

```
<select onchange="if(this.value)loadXMLDoc(this.value)">
  <option value="0" id="selected" selected="selected">Select a car</option>
  <option value="/files/nissan.xml">Nissan</option>
  <option value="/files/mazdaspeed3.xml">Mazdaspeed3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How do i append that parameter in this example? I believe in firebug it shows the response as 304.

Comment: `url=url+'?'+new Date().getTime();` , but see my updated post()

Comment: Your edit above did the trick! Strange why the onclick didnt fire off, but thank you very much.

Comment: This works, for the section option (nissan), but i get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined" when i try to select the third option. Any idea?

Comment: Turns out the error was that i was using .nodeValue and not .data. Works now.

Answer (score 2):

Does any piece of this code work in Chrome on your site for you? If so, how far does it go? If you aren't already, you should use the Chrome developer's tools and set breakpoints in your javascript and step through the code until it stops working as intended.

If I had to take a guess at what is happening -- Chrome probably doesn't like the fact that you're using

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

This line should likely be, instead:

```
xmlhttp.onload
```

---

EDIT CONTENTS:

After looking at your code (based on your comment response), it seems that you will never be able to fire the onclick event of your option. I played around with the code to test this, ensuring it will not run. The following simply will not happen because this event will not fire.

```
<option onclick="alert('test');">Nissan</option>
```

INSTEAD, do not use events from options. Use onchange events from the select.

```
<select onchange="alert(options[selectedIndex].text);">
```

Please try this and tell me if it pleases you. You can use this information to then trigger your xmlhttp logic.

Comment: The playground sample is here.

http://www.brandybrowauto.com/files/test2.html

And the page loads fine but upon selecting one of the values the function does not load up the xml. I tried changing it to .onload instead and still nothing.

Comment: Sorry I didnt give you credit, your answer is exactly right as well. I Simply read Dr. Molle's first. Thank you!